# How to include SpritKit SKScene view as the MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, mkannotationview

Is there a way to use a iOS SpriteKit `SKScene` and its view as the `MKAnnotationView` shown on a `MKMapView`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the view in `-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view` to place a map view. Just keep in mind that SKScene is not really meant for anything other than SKNode.